# Period of a REAL exponential function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

So I don't exactly need my question to be solved for me, I just want to be pointed in the right direction. I need to determine the Fourier coefficients of a function $f(c) = {e}^{-cx}$, where $c$ is any arbitrary constant, in an interval $[0,1]$. If I'm suppose to be using a Fourier series for this, graphing $e^{cx}$ doesn't show some sort of period?

Am I lacking an understanding of the Fourier analysis or am I approaching the problem incorrectly?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you're meant to obtain Fourier coefficients for the period-$1$ function equal on $[0,\,1]$ to $e^{cx}$, i.e. $e^{\{cx\}}$ where $\{z\}:=z-\lfloor z\rfloor$ denotes the fractional part of $z$.

Comment: @J.G. Where does $z$ come from?

Comment: @HRubss I wanted a different name for a dummy variable in the definition of the fractional part.